# Как осуществляется контроль доступного пространства, в случае с базами данных?

Tags: java, android

Знаю что можно вызвать метод, который показывает доступное пространство будь то флешка или внутренняя память. Но если у меня пополняемая база данных, например sqlLite и записи в неё частые и невесомые по объему. Ставить проверку памяти при каждой транзакции? Такого приема я не видел и думаю это затратный способ.  Или может обернуть в try процедуру записи и показывать пользователю toast , если выпало это исключение, вроде более дешевый вариант(кстати тогда приложите к ответу какой эксепшен ловит ошибку, которая выпадает при нехватке памяти.) Какая практика  существует по этому поводу?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю ловить [SQLiteFullException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteFullException.html) ничего постыдного нет

Comment: мм, хорошая штука. Написано, что выпадает, когда база переполнена, это значит память на носителе закончилась или может еще по причине того, что объем БД можно иcскуствено ограничить? имею ввиду sqlLite.

Comment: И то и другое может быть